# How to load data stored in a text file into a PostgreSQL database via Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a text file that contains data in the following format:

```
char char char char
#1   a    b    c

char char char dateTime
#2   d    e    20-12-2012
#3   g    h    8-12-2013
```

I have created 2 tables in PostgreSQL: one with the following datatype structure: `(varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar)` (for the `#1 a b c` record).

The second table that is supposed to hold the rest of the data and has been designed with the following datatype structure: `(varchar,varchar,varchar, dateTime)`. Now, what I'd like to do is load the data given above into my PostgreSQL DB. However, since I am new to PostgreSQL, I am not sure how to load data stored in a text file into the database. Could anybody please give me suggestions on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: You'll need a DB API adapter for PostgreSQL. [Pyscopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) is a popular choice for this. The documentation there should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module or a similar tool to read the file data in as rows of data.

Once you have the data as rows (lists or tuples) in Python, you can create a new connection using a [Python DBI driver](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) like [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/). Establish a connection to PostgreSQL, prepare a statement and execute it once with each data row.

There's lots more info all over the 'net; search for "psycopg tutorial" to start. [Here's one article](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial), though I haven't done anything more than skim read it.